# Passign a variable from python 3.8 to a shell command

Tags: python, python-3.8

How do I pass a variable from a python loop to a shell command within the same python script?

e.g.
Lets say textfile.txt have a list of host names

```
import subprocess

with open("textfile.txt") as f:
    for i in f:
        if 'server01' in i:
            subprocess.run(["scp", "user@<value-of-i>:/path-to-file", "path-to-save"])
```

So when the if command is true, how do I pass that value of i to that scp command?

Many Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use f-strings:

```
        subprocess.run(["scp", f"user@{i.strip()}:/path-to-file", "path-to-save"])
```

Note that passing strings to the command line just like that can be unsafe, depending on if you trust the contents of `textfile.txt` to be safe.

Also, you need to remove the whitespace, because looping over lines leaves in the newlines.

Answer (score 5):

You can pass it in anyway you'd normally do string-formatting.

**str.format:**

```py
    if 'server01' in i:
        subprocess.run(["scp", "user@{}:/path-to-file".format(i), "path-to-save"])
```

**f-strings:**

```py
    if 'server01' in i:
        subprocess.run(["scp", f"user@{i}:/path-to-file", "path-to-save"])
```

**Percentage:**

```py
    if 'server01' in i:
        subprocess.run(["scp", "user@%s:/path-to-file" % i, "path-to-save"])
```

**string concat:**

```py
    if 'server01' in i:
        subprocess.run(["scp", "user@" + i + ":/path-to-file", "path-to-save"])
```

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
subprocess.run(["scp", "user@{}:/path-to-file".format(i), "path-to-save"])
```